# How the styles are used in CSS

Tags: css

Hi I am new to CSS and was playing around. I have this example

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h4>International News</h4>
    <article>
        <h4 class= "headline"> New Developments! </h4>
        <aside>
            <h4>Impact on Markets</h4>
        </aside>
    </article>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
h4 {color:powderblue;}
.headline{color:red;}
article {color:black;font-style:normal;}
aside h4{font-style:italic !important; color:yellow;}
article h4{font-style:normal; color:sienna;}
```

Why does the "inside on markets" h4 is using sienna and not yellow color?
Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

Neither `color:yellow` nor `color:sienna` is [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) (this is good, `!important` is horrible).

`aside h4` and `article h4` both match the element.

`aside h4` and `article h4` both contain 2 type selectors and nothing else that influences specificity, so are equally [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

`article h4` is [defined last](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order), so it is applied last and overrides the previous matching rule.

Comment: Clear answer! @user3497432: you should really look into the link about specificy, this is a classic case about it.

Answer (score 1):

Because code is correctly read from the top to the bottom.

```
aside h4{font-style:italic !important; color:yellow;}
article h4{font-style:normal; color:sienna;}
```

First you give the h4's in `aside` (and it's children) the color yellow.

This is this one:
`<h4>Impact on Markets</h4>`

Then you give the h4's in `article` (and it's children) the color sienna.

It instantly overrides the code. If you switch the position of the lines you can see that it now does get yellow.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6hb3/)

Comment: +1 for explaining that the styles are applied in order. This fact along with explaining how the last style overrides the previous helped!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use following CSS

```
aside > h4{font-style:italic !important; color:yellow;}
article > h4{font-style:normal; color:sienna;}
```

here `>` will force the selector to apply style on direct child/children not to grandchild/grandchildren

Comment: sorry for being stupid to ask what wrong in this answer i have done or i misunderstood the question ??....so that i take care of that next time..plz..Thanks in advance for reply .

Comment: Whilst your answer highlights how more specific CSS could be used, it doesn't answer the question. This is probably why you've been down voted.